# I have a List (ojListView) in which there is a context menu (ojMenu). How do I pass a variable from list to Menu select function.?

Tags: knockout.js, oracle-jet

Below is the Ojet component and I want to pass 'p_id' from the OJet component to the 'contextMenuItemSelect' function in the Menu.

The ui.item.children("a").text() is able to fetch the option selected but I want to get the p_id of the respective list item and based on the option selected will navigate to edit or view.

How can this be done??

Ojet Component

```
        <script type="text/html" id="server_template">
            <li data-bind="attr: {id: $data['p_id']}">
                <div class="oj-flex">

                    <div class="oj-lg-12 oj-md-12 oj-sm-12">
                        <div class="oj-flex row portfolio-list">
                            <!-- Portfolio Name and Description -->
                            <div class="oj-lg-4 oj-sm-12">
                                <h2>
                                    <a href="#" data-bind="text: p_id, click: getView"></a>
                                </h2>

                                <span class="data"><span data-bind="text: desc"></span></span>

                            </div>

                                <div id="menubutton-container">
                                    <button id="menuButton2"
                                      data-bind="

                                        ojComponent: {component: 'ojButton', display: 'icons', 
                                        icons: {start:'demo-icon-font demo-gear-icon-16'}, 
                                        label: 'Button with two icons and no text',
                                        menu: '#myMenu2'}">
                                    </button>

                                // The below span gives the list ID correctly

                                 <span data-bind="text: p_id"></span>

                                  <ul id="myMenu2"  data-bind="attr:{title: p_id},ojComponent: {component: 'ojMenu', select:contextMenuItemSelect}" style="display:none">

                                // The below span always gives the 1st id on the list

                                  <span data-bind="text: p_id"></span>
                                    <!-- ko template: {name: 'menuItemTemplate', foreach: items, as: 'item'} -->
                                    <!-- /ko -->
                                  </ul>
                                </div>

                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </script>
```

Menu Template

```
<script type="text/html" id="menuItemTemplate">
  <li data-bind="css: {'oj-disabled': item.disabled}">
  <a href="#" data-bind="text: name"></a>
  <!-- ko if: item.items -->
   <ul data-bind="template: {name: 'menuItemTemplate', foreach: item.items, as: 'item'}">
   </ul>
 <!-- /ko -->
 </li>
```

JS Function

```
self.contextMenuItemSelect = function( event, ui ) {

      console.log(ui.item);
      var option = ui.item.children("a").text();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have a working code to try it instead of these snippets, but what I would try first is to make sure that the UL element (that has ojMenu binding) has a unique ID attribute. From the sample code it looks like all menus share the same ID "myMenu2". I don't know how ojMenu works exactly but should it look for elements by ID, this could cause troubles (moreover it is not valid HTML code when there are duplicates IDs)